# Css Dropdown absolute doesnt show, but relative does

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build a css dropdown.

I have the main dropdown (the first `ul`) with a `position` of `relative`, and the second dropdown with `position` as `absolute`.

But if I have it on `absolute` it does this:

[image: absolute]

and if I have it on `relative` I get this:

[image: relative]

here is the markup:

```
<li class='active has-sub'>
    <a href="#">
        <div class="profile">
            <img src="images/avatar.png" /> <span>Josh</span> <img src="images/arrow-down-dark.png" class="arrow_down" /><br />
        </div>
    </a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Opt 1</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Opt 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Opt 3</a></li>
        <li class='last'><a href="#">Log out</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

and the css:

```
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu li,
#cssmenu span,
#cssmenu a {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
}
```

** UPDATE **

ochi asked for more code, so I am going to post all the css code relating to the menu itself:

```
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu li,
#cssmenu span,
#cssmenu a {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
#cssmenu {
    line-height: 1;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    width: auto;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu ul:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
#cssmenu a {
    color: #000;
    display: block;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#cssmenu ul {
    list-style: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-center {
    text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
    float: none;
}
#cssmenu.align-center ul ul {
    text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul {
    float: right;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
    text-align: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 12px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #9c9c9c;
        margin-left: -10px;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li.cssno {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li.cssno:hover:after {
    border-bottom: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:first-child > a {
     border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li:first-child > a,
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li:first-child > a {
    border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
}
 #cssmenu.align-right > ul > li:last-child > a {
     border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a {
    color: #fff;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a {
    color: #000;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub {
    z-index: 1;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999999;
}
#cssmenu.align-right .has-sub ul {
    left: auto;
    right: 0;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li {
    *margin-bottom: -1px;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li a {
    background: #0fa1e0;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #31b7f1;
    font-size: 11px;
    display: block;
    line-height: 120%;
    color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li:hover a {
    background: #0c7fb0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a {
    color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu.align-right .has-sub .has-sub ul,
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul ul {
    left: auto;
    right: 100%;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.last > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li:last-child > a,
#cssmenu ul ul ul li.last > a,
#cssmenu ul ul ul li:last-child > a,
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li:last-child > a,
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li.last > a {
    border-bottom: 0;
}
```

and markup of the menu with the nav below it:

```
<header>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <section class="top_bar">
                    <a href="#"><div class="logo"><img src="images/activated_logo_dark.png"></div></a>
                    <div class="profile_info_meta" id="cssmenu">
                        <ul id="cssmenu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">
                                    <div class="item bell">
                                        <img src="images/bell.png" />
                                        <p>7</p>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">
                                    <div class="item calendar">
                                        <img src="images/calendar.png" />
                                        <p>3</p>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="cssno"><div class="item vertical_divider"></div></li>
                            <li class='active has-sub'>
                                <a href="#">
                                    <div class="profile">
                                        <img src="images/avatar.png" /> <span>Josh</span> <img src="images/arrow-down-dark.png" class="arrow_down" /><br />
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#"><span>Opt 1</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Opt 2</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Opt 3</a></li>
                                    <li class='last'><a href="#">Log out</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div> <!-- end of wrapper -->
            <section class="nav">
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <nav>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>  
                            <li><a href="#">Referrals</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Search</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Groups</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">News</a></li> 
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                    <a href="#"><div class="edit_profile">Edit Profile</div></a>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div> <!-- end of wrapper -->
            </section> <!-- end of nav --> 
        </header>
```

When I use `relative`, it pushes the content down like this:

[image: pushes content down]

meanwhile it initially looked like this:

[image: initial]

Comment: the solution is you should use relative positioning and not absolute

Comment: I am not sure we have all the CSS/HTML required to replicate the issue.  Can you post a bit more code?

Comment: @ochi I posted all css code related to the menu

Comment: I just don't see any references to the `#cssmenu` in your HTML

Comment: @ochi the `ul` is inside of a `div` with an `id` of `cssmenu`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSS posted initially was enough to replicate the issue but the HTML wasn't.

I added this

```
<ul id="cssmenu">
        ...
</ul>
```

and it now works:

**DEMO: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aqq601j2/)**

**UPDATED: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aqq601j2/2/)**

Comment: Now it pushes the content below it down, I need it to be positioned `absolute` so that it is over the content below it, not pushing it down

Comment: can you expand on what you mean by 'pushes the content down'? I am not seeing it - **updated** fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/aqq601j2/1/

Comment: put the images in the post

Comment: did you see the updated fiddle? I don't see that behaviour.  is the gray, edit-profile area inside the `<ul>`?

Comment: I did see the updated fiddle, coppied the code and I got the same result. The `edit-profile` is in a completely separate `div` to the `ul`

Comment: weird.  Can you share more HTML then? I don't have enough to go on here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67301/discussion-between-ochi-and-josh-harington).

Answer (score 0):

with absolute position
give top and left in pixels not in %.

Comment: try giving z-index:9999999 maybe it is getting hidden by another div.

Answer (score 0):

here `#cssmenu` not using as parent.,
u change like that

```
.has-sub:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
.has-sub ul {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
}
```

thank you!

Comment: I need the `#cssmenu` there otherwise it has no parent

Comment: I need the dropdown to display above the rest of the content without pushing it down.

Comment: can you upload the content div with css?